# How to develop a string comparision in cython for speed?

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I am tying to do a string comparision between two objects,

```
%load_ext cython # jupyterlab

%%cython --annotate

skills1 = {
    "java": ["java", "j2ee"],
    "python": ["Cython", "pypi"],
    "application development": ["software development"],
}

skills2 = ["python", "j2ee", "software development"]
cdef int count = 0
for i, vals in skills1.items():
    for j in skills2:
        if j == i or j in vals:
            count += 1
            break

print("score", (count / len(coreskills))*100)
```

Due to the --annotate tag I was able to whether there are any python interaction, but all lines except one like was yellow.

So I think I am not optimizing code. Can someone help me in writing this above functionality in cython so I can get speed.

side note: The variables `skills1 and 2` are python dictionary and list which is returned by another function, I don't know how to onvert them to cython dictionary and cython array as well

Comment: "I don't know how to onvert them to cython dictionary and cython array as well" - there's no such thing as a Cython dictionary. A Cython array does exist, but it's really for numeric data so it doesn't help you much]

Comment: Does  `cython` have its own `C` based strings and string methods?  Or are these still Python strings?

Comment: `items()` converts the `dict` to a list (ol lists).  `i` and `j` are python strings.  `j==i` and `j in vals` use python string equality tests.  Python strings are unicode, which is significantly more complicated than the Py2 bytestrings/ASCII, where characters are single bytes (7 bits).  The original strings builtin into `c` were "Strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character", but there are various multibyte string libraries.

Comment: @hpaulj So there's no way I could optimize it any further?

Comment: @DavidW so should I just stick with python if cython doesn't offer much performance benefits. I assumed cython will speed things up.

Comment: One approach would be to use c++ types in Cython. This would be worth it if you could generate your data in Cython, but probably not if the data is coming from Python. Presumably your example if cut down and you have larger sources of data that are loaded somehow?